# Using python pushy to evaluate subfunctions

Tags: python, remote-server

How can I use pushy to evaluate a function that calls another function?  The error I receive is due to the fact that the subfunction does not exist on the remote client.

Example

module test.py:

```
import os
def func1():
    func2()
def func2():
    print os.uname()
```

module main.py

```
import pushy
rc = pushy.connect('ssh:remote_network_address')
proxy_func = rc.compile(test.func1)
proxy_func()
```

I will get the following error:

```
pushy.protocol.proxy.ExceptionProxy: global name 'func2' is not defined
```

If, however, the 'print os.uname()' was located in func1, and no call to func2 is made, the code works as expected.  Basically, how can I tell pushy about func2, and will it be executed on the remote client or locally?  Can I control where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way around this is to call `execute` or `eval` with the function passed in as `globals` like so:

```
import os
def func1():
    func2()

def func2():
    print os.uname()

import pushy
rc = pushy.connect('local:')
# runs:
rc.execute("func1()", globals={'func1':func1})
# runs:
rc.eval("func1()", globals={'func1':func1})

# close 
rc.close()
```

I get results like:

> ('Linux', 'piane', '3.8.0-38-generic', '#56~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 13 16:22:48 
>   UTC 2014', 'x86_64')

It is not clear to me how you would do this via `compile`, since it does not take `globals` or `locals`.